# I've Github PDF reader working with my Swift code with Test.pdf file , but how to I read the pdf files stored at Parse database?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, parse-platform

1. This is current swift code of PDF reader have to know the file and path:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController , ReaderViewControllerDelegate{

   @IBAction func didClickOpenPDF(sender: AnyObject) {


   let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Test", ofType: "pdf")
   let document:ReaderDocument = ReaderDocument.withDocumentFilePath(file, password: nil)
   print(file)
   print("DOcument = ", document)

   if (document != "")
   {
       print("not empty")
       let readerViewController:ReaderViewController = ReaderViewController(readerDocument: document)
       readerViewController.delegate = self


       readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
       readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen


       [self.presentViewController(readerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)]
   }
   }
   ```

   2. This is parse database structure:

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRVhy.png)

3. so how am I to access and read the "bookfile" field and know the path directory? 
   can anyone help and provide some code in swift-2 which I can use? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have do the same type of functionality. 
Try below code. May be help it. Do the require changes in below code as you need.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"ModelHome")
query.whereKey("guestName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock 
{
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil 
  {
      // The find succeeded.
      print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
     // Do something with the found objects
     if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] 
     {
         for object in objects
         {
            print(object.objectId)

           //Get PDF Data from Object.
           let userPDFFile = object["docs"] as PFFile
           userPDFFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock
           {
             (pdfData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil 
            {
                if let pdfData = pdfData 
               {
                  //Do the your required code here after getting pdf data.
               }
            }
         }
      }
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    // Log details of the failure
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replied.

Comment: Sorry can I check how to handle the line 
if let pdfData = pdf Data , as I new to swift and parse. I try to assign the pdfData to my previous code
 let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pdfData", ofType: "pdf")
                                      
 let document:ReaderDocument = ReaderDocument.withDocumentFilePath(file, password: nil)
when I print the file = nil and 
system crash fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at ReaderDOcument line.

Comment: no worry ! I finally manages find a way to get the url. Thanks

Comment: @vincent If you have helpful this answer then plz mark as accepted answer. So other people can find it as helpful.